# text matching with logical function?

Tags: excel

Please help me to formulate the following formula:

Actually I am trying to make a costing sheet for recipes.. I am listing all the items in `sheet 1` and on `sheet 2` all recipes with their quantities of items..

```
sheet 1 
    A                B     
1 item           price/gm   
2 chicken         10

Sheet 2
   A                B                C  
1 item            Qty (in gm)       cost
2 chicken         150              formula?
```

now in `sheet 2 C2` I need a formula that matches `sheet2 A2` with `sheet1` column A and then multiply `sheet2 B2` with `sheet1 B2`.. and this will same for all the items in `sheet2`.. if I put any item in `sheet2` it looks up in `sheet1` and then multiply the price with qty in `sheet2`..

Answer (score 0):

Use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=B2*VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet 1'!A:B,2,false)
```